# Automate tasks in Eclipse by buttonpress

Tags: eclipse, ant

Is there an easy way (i.e. not developing a custom plug-in) to create a button to my task bar that would run a specific Ant target? It doesn't have to be native - it's ok if it escapes to the OS shell, or other magic trickery.

I'm using Eclipse Ganymede on OSX.

Answer (score 1):

Try [Eclipse Monkey](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse_Monkey_Overview). The plugin is dead (no further development) but it should work.